# I need to extract Ports for Vlan Id using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
VLAN  Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
1    default                          active    Po10, Po20, Po30, Po40, Po50
                                                Eth1/1, Eth1/2, Eth1/3, Eth1/4
                                                Eth1/5, Eth1/6, Eth1/7, Eth1/8                                                                                                
2    native                           active    Po10, Po20, Po30, Po40, Po50
                                                Eth1/5, Eth1/6, Eth1/13, Eth1/14
```

As above is the text file. I need ports for particular vlan id in Dictionary format.

```
[ {'1':'Po10', 'Po20', 'Po30', 'Po40', 'Po50','Eth1/1', 'Eth1/2','Eth1/3',' Eth1/4','Eth1/5', 'Eth1/6', 'Eth1/7', 'Eth1/8'},{'2':'Po10', 'Po20', 'Po30', 'Po40', 'Po50','Eth1/5', 'Eth1/6', 'Eth1/13',' Eth1/14'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary is not valid, if want dict of lists use:

```
d = df.set_index('VLAN')['Ports'].str.split(', ').to_dict()
print (d)
{1: ['Po10', 'Po20', 'Po30', 'Po40', 'Po50', 'Eth1/1', 'Eth1/2', 
     'Eth1/3', 'Eth1/4', 'Eth1/5', 'Eth1/6', 'Eth1/7', 'Eth1/8'], 
 2: ['Po10', 'Po20', 'Po30', 'Po40', 'Po50', 'Eth1/5', 'Eth1/6', 'Eth1/13', 'Eth1/14']}
```

Also is possible create list of dictionaries:

```
d1 = [{k:x} for k, v in d.items() for x in v]
print (d1)
[{1: 'Po10'}, {1: 'Po20'}, {1: 'Po30'}, {1: 'Po40'}, {1: 'Po50'}, {1: 'Eth1/1'}, 
 {1: 'Eth1/2'}, {1: 'Eth1/3'}, {1: 'Eth1/4'}, {1: 'Eth1/5'}, 
 {1: 'Eth1/6'}, {1: 'Eth1/7'}, {1: 'Eth1/8'}, 
 {2: 'Po10'}, {2: 'Po20'}, {2: 'Po30'}, {2: 'Po40'}, {2: 'Po50'}, 
 {2: 'Eth1/5'}, {2: 'Eth1/6'}, {2: 'Eth1/13'}, {2: 'Eth1/14'}]
```

Or is possible create dict of string:

```
d2 = df.set_index('VLAN')['Ports'].to_dict()
print (d2)

{1: 'Po10, Po20, Po30, Po40, Po50, Eth1/1, Eth1/2, Eth1/3, Eth1/4, Eth1/5, Eth1/6, Eth1/7, Eth1/8', 
 2: 'Po10, Po20, Po30, Po40, Po50, Eth1/5, Eth1/6, Eth1/13, Eth1/14'}
```